# Get Generic Type from Type

Tags: typescript

Can the generic type be retrieved from a `Promise` type?

For instance, the following type:

```ts
type Example = Promise<boolean>;
```

Is it possible to extract the generic type, `boolean`, into its own type? For instance:

```ts
type BooleanPromise = Promise<boolean>;
type Value = genericsof Example[0]; // boolean
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to extract the generic type argument from a generic type instantiation:

```
type Example = Promise<boolean>;

type BooleanPromise = Promise<boolean>;
type Value = BooleanPromise extends Promise<infer V> ? V : never // boolean
```

You can even create a generic type that extracts the argument from any promise instantiation:

```
type PromiseValue<T> = T extends Promise<infer V> ? V : never 
type Value2 = PromiseValue<BooleanPromise>
```

You can read more about conditional types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

a, a2 is boolean

```
import { ITSResolvable, ITSUnpacked } from 'ts-type';

export type Example = Promise<boolean>;

export type ValueTypeOfExample = ITSUnpacked<Example>;

let a: ValueTypeOfExample;

a = true;

// @ts-ignore err when without @ts-ignore
a = 0;
// @ts-ignore err when without @ts-ignore
a = '';
```